# When I insert a gradient image to my Collection View Cell the label text darkens on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app where I show the most popular movies. When loading the movies into a Collection View Cell, i'm trying to get a gradient experience below the poster so the title of the movie is more readable, but when I insert the image, the label color is no longer white and it darkens with the image.

Any Ideas why this might be happening?

Also, I'm new to Swift, so is there any simpler alternatives?

Thanks,

[This is the app:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA4cK.jpg)

As you can see in this image, the label is dark grey, even though it is set to be White Color.

[This is the Collection View Cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3VBC.png)

Comment: Make sure the `alpha` value of gradientImageView is 1.0 and gradient Colors have `opacity` of 1.0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some how your label goes under the gradient imageView on z axis. You can debug it with debug view hierarchy when you run the app. If so you need to find out what code block send it to the back of imageView.

If you share your CollectionViewCell class I can give you more help.